# because $ Tr (a) = Tr (a ^ p) $ where $ a \in \mathbb {F} _q$ (finite field) and p is characteristic of this field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Can anyone explain to me why this relationship? Where Tr is the absolute trace function $ Tr: \mathbb{F}_q \to \mathbb{F}_p $

Comment: $a\mapsto a^p$ is an automorphism of $\Bbb F_q$.

Comment: What you wrote is the Frobenius automorphism $\phi(\alpha) = \alpha^p$. For $q = p^n$ the trace is $Tr_{\mathbb{F}_q/\mathbb{F}_p}(\alpha) =\sum_{k=1}^{n} \phi^k(\alpha)= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha^{p^k} $. For $a \in \mathbb{F}_p, Tr_{\mathbb{F}_q/\mathbb{F}_p}(a) = an$. And the norm is  $N_{\mathbb{F}_q/\mathbb{F}_p}(\alpha) = \prod_{k=1}^n \phi^k(\alpha) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \alpha^{p^k} = \alpha^{(p^n-1)/(p-1)}$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $q=p^n$

$$\begin{aligned}Tr(a^p)&=(a^p)+(a^p)^p+\cdots+(a^p)^{p^{n-2}}+(a^p)^{p^{n-1}}\\
&=a^p+a^{p^2}+\cdots+a^{p^{n-1}}+a^{p^n}\\
&=a^p+a^{p^2}+\cdots+a^{p^{n-1}}+a\\
&=Tr(a).
\end{aligned}$$